# React native app is crashing only on release build

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, sms

I use react-native-android-sms-listener (https://github.com/CentaurWarchief/react-native-android-sms-listener) - simple package for listening sms. But it not working on release build. When SMS recived I have crash without error message.

In android logs I found this:

```
ReactNativeJS: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'arguments.[0].indexOf('Requiring module \'NativeModules\' by name')')
```

On the debug build always works fine.

ReactNative 0.55.4

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14364
Need removing all console.warn before building release.

Comment: I got the same error without having any console.warn present. How else can this be solved?

Comment: @AndrewSteinheiser try this:
`
if (!__DEV__) {
  console = {}
  console.log = () => null
  console.warn = () => null
  console.error = () => null
}
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14364](http://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14364) Need removing all **console.warn** before building release.

or

```
if (!__DEV__) {
  console = {}
  console.log = () => null
  console.warn = () => null
  console.error = () => null
}
```

Comment: Could you add more verbal explanation to your post?